# How to launch camera and send photo taken to another activity

Tags: android

I'm trying this for a few days now, but i can't seem to get it.
Here's my code, to launch the camera and send to another activity.

```
       button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent iSecond=new Intent(getActivity(),ShowImage.class);
            iSecond.putExtra("image_path",image_path);
            startActivity(iSecond);
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Launching Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(imageIntent, REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA);

        }
    });
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Intent send = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowImage.class);
        send.putExtra("pictureUri", selectedImage.toString());
        startActivity(send);
    }
}
```

Now in the receiving activity i have the following code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.showImage);
    iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("pictureUri")));
}
```

Please someone help me out with this, this is killing me!

Answer (score 2):

Try This one, its working.

**MainActivity.java** :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 100;
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    Button btnCapture;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("image", thumbnail);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

**NextActivity.java** :

```
ImageView imgView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imageview);

        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Bitmap image = (Bitmap) extras.get("image");
            if (image != null) {
                imgView.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Manifest.xml** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NextActivity" />
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside if condition in `onActivityResult`.

```
String pathofpic = getApplication().getExternalFilesDir("MyImages")+ "image_001.jpg"; 
Intent send = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowImage.class);
send.putExtra("picturePath", picturePath);
startActivity(send);
```

Now in your ShowImage.class

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String pathofpic = getIntent().getStringExtra("picturePath");
yourimageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathofpic));
```

Comment: getContentResolver() is method of class android.content.Context, so to call it you definitely need an instance of Context ( Activity or Service for example). I have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm getting nullpointer exception at Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

Comment: please update your question with current implementation that you have tried.

Comment: why did you remove your if statement. Try inside if condition only.  I don't see any if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FROM_CAMERA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null).

Comment: done that! still not receiving image in second activity!

Comment: try to print picturepath in log in second activity. or debug it to check whether you're getting null or anything else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89474/discussion-between-tauqir-and-bappi-bazzi).

Answer (score 0):

### Abstract

You do not need to resolve that URI to a file path in your `onActivityResult` method. You can instead pass that URI object to your second activity and there extracting it from the Intent and applying to ImageView by `setImageUri`.

### Demonstration

Your `onActivityResult` should looks like the code below.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    Intent send = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowImage.class);
    send.putExtra("pictureUri", selectedImage.toString());
    startActivity(send);
}
```

And in your second activity:

```
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.showImage);
iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("pictureUri")));
```

Comment: @bappibazzi Oh, sorry. it's `setImageURI`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString at Line :         iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("pictureUri")));

Comment: @bappibazzi That's mean in you should take a picture at Camera Activity. Not taking a picture results in that URI to be `null` (I think but I am not sure).

Comment: @bappibazzi Make sure those strings passed as the key to this Intent is the same.

Comment: So please check which object is `null` at this line.

Comment: Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
is not getting any data from camera intent

Comment: fileUri in camera intent in also null

Comment: @bappibazzi As I've searched around now. It seems you should first create the destination file (i.e. that jpg file) as an empty file by `createNewFile()` method. Also for this you should add permission for writing external storage.

Comment: how to do that now?Please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89506/discussion-between-abforce-and-bappi-bazzi).